# What is sent to the server when I modify the Host: header with FiddlerScript?

Tags: fiddler

I'm using FiddlerScript to modify the request as follows:

```
 oSession.oRequest["Host"] = "www.example.com";
 oSession["x-overridehost"] = "Dotted.Quad.IP.Address";
```

Now, when I inspect one of the modified sessions, I see this:

```
GET https://www.example.com/rest/of/url HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

My question is whether the host name from the full URL is passed to the server, or if the server is only sent something like:

```
GET /rest/of/url HTTP/1.1
```

in the first line of the request. I don't have access to the server's encryption key, so I can't use something like Wireshark to examine the exact traffic that is going out over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps at all, I see the following when performing a GET to an application running on my local machine:

```
GET http://localhost:51425/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:51425
.
.
.
```

GET should always include a fully qualified domain name.

Comment: Lots of other tools I see just record the path and query part of the URL in the GET line. That's why I'm asking. 

Looking at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.3, it looks like the usual (origin-form) line would be:

`GET /just/a/path?followed-by=query-string-parameters HTTP/1.1
Host: with.a.hostname.here`

But with a proxy involved, the client must use the absolute-form:

`GET https://hostname.goes.here/followed/by?the-complete=url HTTP/1.1
Host: must.still.be.included`

But I was wondering if Fiddler forces all URLs into the absolute form.

Comment: Ah I hear you. The text I posted is from inspecting the headers using Visual Studio running a web app I created just for you.